# What does "esac" mean at the end of a bash case statement? Is it required?

Tags: bash, case

I have found multiple examples of "esac" appearing at the end of a bash case statement but I have not found any clear documentation on it's use.  The man page uses it, and even has an index on the word (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-esac), but does not define it's use.  Is it the required way to end a case statement, best practice, or pure technique?

Comment: The index entry for `esac` points exactly where it should — to the line that defines it and illustrates that it's required.

Comment: @hobbs, you are correct that the index points to the line that illustrates its use but it does not define it in any way, especially compared to the way it describes the use of other characters like "|" or ";" or ";;".  Now that I've read the answer(s), the backwards spelling "case" appears to be such a de facto standard for ending commands that most experienced users would take it for granted.

Comment: If you didn't have `esac` or something like it, how do you think it would be able to tell where the end of the `case` statement is?

Comment: It defines it as being part of the syntax of the `case` statement, in the same way that `else`, `elif`, and `fi` are defined as being part of the syntax of an `if` statement. It doesn't have any semantics of its own, so there isn't anything to say about it, but it's at the end of the definition of a `case` statement, so it's where a `case` statement ends. The fact that it's `case` spelled backwards is a convenient curiosity, but the computer doesn't care, it just knows that it's looking for a certain word.

Comment: @hobbs "...there isn't anything to say about it..." yet you just wrote a paragraph of explanation of why there's nothing to say about it. The important thing is to just understand the intent of the "esac". That's why this question has a straight answer with a fair number of upvotes.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Like `fi` for `if` and `done` for `for`, `esac` is the required way to end a `case` statement.

`esac` is `case` spelled backward, rather like `fi` is `if` spelled backward.  I don't know why the token ending a `for` block is not `rof`.

Comment: You mean why isn't it `od` to end a `do` block?  :)

Comment: Imagine having to type `\od` every time you wanted to use that utility! Which is rare, but my point stands ;)

Comment: the "for" is a loop it has to know when to stop, so they HAVE ta use the word done so it will stop looping, otherwise it won't?

Comment: @Wildcard It's `fi` and not `neht`, so by analogy it would be `rof` (or `elihw`) and not `od` (also, of course, `od` is already taken) ... but maybe this is expecting too much self-consistency out of one of the most self-inconsistent languages there is.

Comment: It's `done` because the statement begins with `do`, not `for` or `while`.

Answer (score 82):

The `esac` keyword is indeed a required delimiter to end a `case` statement in `bash` and most shells used on Unix/Linux excluding the `csh` family.

The original [Bourne shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell) was created by [Steve Bourne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_R._Bourne) who previously worked on [ALGOL68](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALGOL_68). This language invented this reversed word technique to delimit blocks.

```
case/esac

if/fi

do/od
```

The latter is no more `do/od` but `do/done` in Bourne and all the derived shells including `bash` because `od` was already existing as a Unix command since its inception ([**o**ctal **d**ump](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-1st/1/od)).

Note that `do/done` functional blocks are introduced by either the `for`, the `while`, or the `until` instructions. `for`, `while` and `until` do not need to be terminated as `done` is sufficient. That's the reason why there is no need for the hypothetical `rof` and `elihw` tokens.

Comment: Sure it made sense to Steve ;-)

Answer (score 9):

The "`esac`" terminates an earlier "`case`" to form a "[code-block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_%28programming%29)".

In Algol68 they are used, generally the reversed character sequence of the introducing keyword is used for terminating the enclosure, e.g. `( if ~ then ~ else ~ fi, case ~ in ~ out ~ esac, for ~ while ~ do ~ od ).`

I would call them "Guarded Blocks" after [Edsger Dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edsger_W._Dijkstra) and his [Guarded Command Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guarded_Command_Language#Selection:_if).

`od` presumably was not used in the Bourne Shell because of the pre-existence of the Unix ["od" command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Od_%28Unix%29).

***The history:***

The "Guarded Block" idea appear to have come from  [ALGOL 68](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALGOL_68) e.g. English:

```
proc days in month = (int year, month)int:

  case month in
    31,
    if year mod 4=0 ∧ year mod 100≠0  ∨  year mod 400=0 then 29 else 28 fi,
    31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31
  esac;
```

The Soviet's [Algol68 LGU implementation](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/ALGOL/algol68impl) did the same: In English Algol68's reverent case statement reads `case ~ in ~ out ~ esac`, in Cyrillic this reads `выб ~ в ~ либо ~ быв`.

Then in 1975 Algol68's code-blocks were borrowed by [Edsger Dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edsger_W._Dijkstra) for his [Guarded Command Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guarded_Command_Language#Selection:_if). e.g.

```
if a ≥ b → max := a
| b ≥ a → max := b
fi
```

Presumably Dijstra used "Guarded Blocks" to overcome the [Dangling else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else#C) ambiguity implemented in [Algol60](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALGOL_58#ALGOL_58.27s_influence_on_ALGOL_60) and then re-engineered in the [C Programming Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29).  (cf. [shift-reduce conflict.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser#Conflicts_in_the_constructed_tables))

Finally - from Algol68 - "`esac`" made it into the 1977 [Bourne shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell) (where you discovered `esac`) courtesy of [Stephen R. Bourne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_R._Bourne) who had developed an early Algol68 compiler called [ALGOL 68C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALGOL_68C).

Famously Stephen also used these same Guarded Blocks in a "C header file" called [macro.h](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/src/cmd/sh/mac.h)

```
#define IF  if(
#define THEN    ){
#define ELSE    } else {
#define ELIF    } else if (
#define FI  ;}
```

The notable software geniuses [Landon Curt Noll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landon_Curt_Noll) and [Larry Bassel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Bassel) stumbled upon Steve's macro.h code in 1984 while employed at National Semiconductor's Genix porting group and struggled to understand its application.  And so Landon & Larry then created the [International Obfuscated C Code Contest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Obfuscated_C_Code_Contest)...

From 1984 until today there have been [several thousand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages) other "better" programming languages that do not use Dijkstra's Guarded Commands.  And Steven Bourne's use of them in `macro.h` is now often cited in the "Software Development Dissertations" of IT undergraduates as proof they were not sleep in lectures. :-)

Comment: What's `case out`? never seen that syntax

Comment: @Dani_l That's Algol68 syntax not adopted by the bourne shell.

Comment: Why would they call it `od` even if it wasn't already taken? Wouldn't it be `rof` or `elihw`?

Comment: Picking `do ~ od`, `if ~ fi` and `case ~ esac` simply means that endless future generations of undergrads will be able to ponder Algol68 and add a simple "critique" of Algol68 into their final year project, without having to actually write more then a page (line?) of Algol68 code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's required.  As Jacob points out above, the logic of it is the same as `if`/`fi`.  Traditional C comment delimiters `/*` and `*/` also pair similarly.  Because C was written so that Unix could be written mostly in C, with the minimum of assembly code, with a large overlap between the C and Unix development teams, it's reasonable to assume a common source of the notion that the closing equivalent of a multi-character block delimiter should be the same sequence of characters in reverse order.

In contrast, loops like `for`, `while`, and `until` use `do`...`done` instead of reversing character order, so there is **some** inconsistency.

Comment: Syntax came from Bourne, which again was inspired by ALGOL.