# Was `esac` intentionally `case` just in reverse?

Tags: shell-script, history, case

I just realized that in shell scripting `esac`, the closing statement for `case` is just `case` reversed. This may be a stupid question but does `esac` actually mean something (ie an abbreviation) or was it chosen solely due to it being the literal opposite of `case`?

Comment: Have you also seen `if` and `fi`?

Comment: I think https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/256175/70524 from the above post covers this well

Answer (score 0):

Simple and specific questions allow for short answers.

Answer : **YES**